# Matlab - Generating HMM

Tags: matlab, hidden-markov-models, viterbi

Let's assume that I have a random set of observations:

`obs = [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`

These observations represent 1 state in the HMM. In Matlab, I want to model these observations so then I can use the Viterbi algorithm in order to create a kind of classifier.

The problem that I am having is that I don't really know where to start in terms of generating the models in Matlab. The functionality in the toolbox does not seem to have this.

Is there a specific library out there, which will enable me to carry out such a procedure in order to model a series of observations?

Comment: to define a discret hmm you need atleast: a number of states `n` for your model, a `n X n` transition probability, a list of `m` posible  observations (emissions) and a `m X n` matrix with the probabilities for each emission in each state. What you have is a series of observations, from that alone you can not define a HMM.

Comment: @ben Thanks! But, I do have a library in C++ that can generate a HMM based just on observations and giving the total number of states? This calculates the transition probabilities and emissions.

Answer (score 2):

to define a discret hmm you need atleast: a number of states `n` for your model, a `n X n` transition probability, a list of `m` posible  observations (emissions) and a `n X m` matrix with the probabilities for each emission in each state. What you have is a series of observations, from that alone you can not define a HMM.

So i would start by having a look at [this](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/hidden-markov-models-hmm.html) tutorial form mathworks to get a grasp of the basics. The functions used there are part of the statistics toolbox.

Then you start by creating a guess for the number of stats in your HMM. Let's say you have 2 stats(like in the tutorial mentioned above)
The next step would be the create a initial guess for the emission and transition matrices. if your posible emissions are `1 2 3 4 5` and your states are `2`then you get a `2x5` Emission probability matrix and a `2x2` transition matrix.

Now lets assume you guess that state 1 produces `1 2 3` and  state 2 produces `4 5` then (evenly distributed) your emission matrix would look like this:

```
>> emis=[1/3 1/3 1/3 0 0; 0 0 0 1/2 1/2]
emis =
    0.3333    0.3333    0.3333         0         0
         0         0         0    0.5000    0.5000
```

you also guess that states do change from state 1 to 2 after a few emissins then stay there. your guess would kinda look like this:

```
>> trans = [.8 .2; 0 1]
trans =
    0.8000    0.2000
         0    1.0000
```

you can have a look what your HMM would generate:

```
>> [seq,states] = hmmgenerate(6, trans, emis)
seq =
     2     1     3     2     4     5

states =
     1     1     1     1     2     2
```

from that point you use observation series to train your HMM with the functions `hmmestimate` or `hmmtrain`.